# Unusual column comparisons and query performance

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2016, except, query-performance

We have some consultants working on expanding an inhouse data warehouse.  I was doing a code review and ran across this pattern in all of the load procs:

```
    MERGE [EDHub].[Customer].[Class] AS TARGET
    USING (
        SELECT <columns>
        FROM [dbo].[vw_CustomerClass]
            WHERE JHAPostingDate = @PostingDate   
        ) AS SOURCE
        ON  TARGET.BankId = SOURCE.BankId       -- This join is on the business keys
            AND TARGET.Code = SOURCE.Code
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET  
        THEN
            <INSERT Statement>
    WHEN MATCHED
        AND TARGET.IsLatest = 1
        AND EXISTS (
            SELECT SOURCE.[HASH]   
            EXCEPT          
            SELECT TARGET.[Hash]
            )
        THEN 
            <UPDATE Statement>
```

The gist is, if we have a new business key, insert but if the business key exists and the hash of the attributes don't match our current row then  update the old row and insert a new one (later in the code).  It all works fine but I paused when I got to this code

```
AND EXISTS (
            SELECT SOURCE.[HASH]   
            EXCEPT          
            SELECT TARGET.[Hash]
            )
```

It seems overly complicated compared to SOURCE.[HASH] <> TARGET.[Hash].  The EXCEPT will do an accurate NULL comparison but in our case hashes will never be NULL (or we have bigger problems).  I want our code to be easy to read so that when someone has to maintain it, it doesn't confuse.  I asked our consultants about it and they speculated that it might be faster because of set operations but I decided to write a simple test (test code below).

The first thing I noticed was the EXISTS/EXCEPT had a more complicated query plan but that's not always bad

I ran each select client statistics on and the <> join yielded total execution time of 12,000 vs 25,000 with the EXISTS/EXCEPT.  I want to take this to our consultants with the request to refactor that statement but wanted to get feedback here on:

1. is this a good test? - am I missing anything?
2. is there a case where EXISTS/EXCEPT would be a better comparison?

Test script:

```
CREATE TABLE r (hash VARBINARY(8000))
CREATE TABLE l (hash VARBINARY(8000))

SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @x INT = 10000
WHILE @x <> 0 BEGIN

   INSERT INTO dbo.r ( hash ) SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA2_256',CAST(NEWID() AS VARCHAR(200)))
   INSERT INTO dbo.l ( hash ) SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA2_256',CAST(NEWID() AS VARCHAR(200)))    

   SET @x = @x-1
END

INSERT INTO dbo.r ( hash ) VALUES ( NULL  )
INSERT INTO dbo.l ( hash ) VALUES ( NULL  )

SELECT COUNT(1) 
FROM dbo.l
CROSS JOIN dbo.r 
WHERE ISNULL(r.hash,0) <> ISNULL(l.hash,0)

SELECT COUNT(1) 
FROM dbo.l
CROSS JOIN dbo.r 
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT r.hash except select l.HASH)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't like `ISNULL` with sentinel values, it requires picking values that can't ever legitimately appear in the data now or forever after and personally I find expressions containing these more difficult to reason about.

For your test rig I tried four different ways of expressing the query and got the stated results.

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM   dbo.l
       CROSS JOIN dbo.r
WHERE  r.hash <> l.hash
        OR ( r.hash IS NULL
             AND l.hash IS NOT NULL )
        OR ( l.hash IS NULL
             AND r.hash IS NOT NULL )
```

> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 30968 ms,  elapsed time =
>   8230 ms.

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM   dbo.l
       CROSS JOIN dbo.r
WHERE  ISNULL(r.hash, 0) <> ISNULL(l.hash, 0)
```

> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 31594 ms,  elapsed time =
>   9230 ms.

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM   dbo.l
       CROSS JOIN dbo.r
WHERE  EXISTS(SELECT r.hash
              EXCEPT
              SELECT l.HASH)
```

> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 46531 ms,  elapsed time =
>   13191 ms.

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM   dbo.l
       CROSS JOIN dbo.r
WHERE  NOT EXISTS(SELECT r.hash
                  INTERSECT
                  SELECT l.HASH)
```

> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 23812 ms,  elapsed time =
>   6760 ms.

So on that basis the last one would be a clear winner - along with a code comment with a link to [Undocumented Query Plans: Equality Comparisons](http://web.archive.org/web/20180422151947/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/06/22/undocumented-query-plans-equality-comparisons.aspx) for anyone unfamiliar with the pattern.

But you should test whether this pattern is reproducible with your actual `MERGE` query too.

Answer (score 4):

I would agree with your findings. The `EXCEPT` pattern that your consultants wrote handles NULL values, and is also a really nice way to manage a very large number of comparison columns.

But if the column cannot be NULL and performance suffers, I suppose there's no point in keeping it.

Your test *could* be inaccurate in the following regards:

- The original queries a view, while your test queries a heap.
- The original query may have a considerably different data volume, whereas you're trying 100 000 rows. Plans are generated differently, depending on the estimated number of rows they will result in.
- Is the original column *really* varbinary(8000)? That sounds awfully wide for a hash value, and column widths affect memory grants, and ultimately performance.

This pattern may be a general solution for column comparisons, generated by a BIML package or similar ETL tool.

Comment: All good points - I might run some live data tests this week on some of the larger tables.  The varbinary(8000) is what hashbytes() outputs by default (at least for SHA2_256 which they are using)